# ARIA main role changes screenreading order

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

Given the following HTML structure:

```
<body>
<div style="display: table;" id="main">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <p>Option 1</p>
        <p>Text 1</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <p>Option 2</p>
        <p>Text 2</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
        <p>Option 3</p>
        <p>Text 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

If `#main` is assigned an ARIA main role (`role="main"` as an attribute), the screenreading order for this structure will be "Option 1 Option 2 Option 3 Text 1 Text 2 Text 3". However, if that is not set, the reading order will be "Option 1 Text 1 Option 2 Text 2 Option 3 Text 3".

I'd like the second possibility to be read, however, I'd also like to keep that element assigned to a `main` role. How to avoid this behavior? Is there a reason for it? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a bug, but that does not matter because your markup is terribly inaccessible and needs to be changed.

This markup violates two WCAG 2 AA success criteria:

- [1.3.1 Info and Relationships](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-programmatic.html)

  The markup violates this because the relationship between the labels/headers ("Option 1", "option 2" etc.) and their content is not explicit.
- [4.1.2 Name, Role, Value and State](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/ensure-compat-rsv.html)

  The markup violates this because the role of the label/header is not explicit

So my recommendation is the following:

- Put the tabular data into an HTML `<table>` element with all the appropriate markup. Use scope attributes to indicate the relationship between headers and data and use `<th>` elements for the headers.
- Put a `<div>` wrapper around that table with the `role="main"` or use a `<main>` element.

Comment: Thanks for the guides. I did have heading tags for the *Option* labels, I just omitted them from the question as I thought it wouldn't be pertinent -- clearly, I was wrong. However, my intent is to present this(http://cl.ly/akBV). Would a `table` really be the best way to go to illustrate this sort of content for screen reader users?

Comment: Do you mean the left table?

Comment: No – I mean these three horizontally aligned `div`s.

Comment: probably better to mark them up as `<div><h2>heading</h2><div>Content</div></div>` and use RWD styles to get them to resize appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Which screen reader are you using?  I attempted this with NVDA (latest update) and it seemed to read the way you wanted with the `role="main"` added.  However, I did add in the `role="columnheader"`, which may help your cause.

```
<style>
    #container { display: table; }
    .tc { display: table-cell; }
</style>

<div role="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="tc">
            <span role="columnheader">Option 1</span>
            <p>Text 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tc">
            <span role="columnheader">Option 2</span>
            <p>Text 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tc">
            <span role="columnheader">Option 3</span>
            <p>Text 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That said, I agree with @unobf and @unor about markup. Also, using the `"display: table"` in terms of the layout might not be the best way to accomplish this, though it can have [valid usages](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero). Hope this helps.